# How to store the file names in array from python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and using  python2.7 in linux, I wrote the small python program as below, but i want to store the each filename into one `variable(index_list[1],...)`.

```
index_list=[]
index_list=commands.getoutput('find /etl/input/ -maxdepth 6 -iname "*tmp" ')

print index_list[1]
```

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use os library:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir

```
import os

mylist = os.listdir(path)
```

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem , but i want to use the *find command* in my program and output will be stored in array format. example my find command get the 4 filenames, each file name should be stored in separate variable  like var[1],var[2]...etc

Comment: So save output from `commands.getoutput('yourcommandhere')` to variable and then split it by '\n' ex: `index_list = index_list.split('\n')`

Answer (score 4):

you can try his

```
import os 
from pprint import pprint 

files = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))


pprint(files)
```